# JetBrains Rider: how to enable javascript & css inspections for IE8 compat

Tags: rider

A code inspection warning came up for some CSS inside an ASPX page, saying that `div:last-of-type` wasn't compatible with IE8.  Rider gave me an option to disable inspections for browser compatibility.  As soon as I did that, I realized it was a mistake and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> didn't work to undo.

How can I restore the inspections for browser compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect element using f12
[Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968260(v=vs.85).aspx)